# Document version support in Cosmos DB. Does UNION work?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Given these two document versions:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "tags": ["first","second"],
  "version": 1,
}
```

And:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "tags": [
    {"name": "third"},
    {"name": "forth"}
  ],
  "version": 2,
}
```

My first attempt to normalize them on reading was:

```
SELECT VALUE t
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.tags
WHERE c.version = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT VALUE t.name
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.tags
WHERE c.version = 2
```

It looks like that UNION is not supported. What is the best way to deal with versioning then? I would prefer a single aggregated query to deal with all versions in a unified way if possible.

Comment: Are your format of version documents regular? i.e: v1 t/ v2 t.name/v3 t/v4 t.name......

Comment: @JayGong Format could change unpredictably (as usual), so I am looking for a general reshape-on-read syntax to keep things compatible with the latest version. Not so big fun of multiple requests or mixing version translation logic into one monolithic peace of code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using stored procedure in the cosmos db. Please refer to my sample code:

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.version,c.tags FROM root c',
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            else {
                var returnResult = [];
                for(var i = 0;i<feed.length;i++){
                    var tagArray = feed[i].tags;
                    if(tagArray[0].name == null){
                        for(var j = 0;j<tagArray.length;j++)
                           returnResult.push(tagArray[j]) 
                    }else {
                        for(var j = 0;j<tagArray.length;j++)
                        returnResult.push(tagArray[j].name)
                    }
                }
                getContext().getResponse().setBody(returnResult);
            }
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

My sample documents :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "tags": [
            "first",
            "second"
        ],
        "version": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "third"
            },
            {
                "name": "forth"
            }
        ],
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "third"
            },
            {
                "name": "forth"
            }
        ],
        "version": 3
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "tags": [
            "first",
            "second"
        ],
        "version": 4
    }
]
```

Execute result:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Does this result actually you want?

Comment: Yes, it works theoretically, thanks. But I need to say that amount of boilerplate work for this simple obvious scenario is enormous, while readability and maintainability of the code is basically below any standards because of product design issues. Microsoft in its distilled best - I think I would personally consider Mongo... :)

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
SELECT VALUE c.version = 1 ? t : t.name
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.tags
```

But it would be difficult to support multiple versions. I would prefer to deal with all version projections independently...